# Adding WebView to CollectionView without using MainStoryboard

Tags: swift, webview, collectionview

I've been working on CollectionView with ImageView in each cells. Now I'm wondering how to add WebView working the same way as ImageView. I want it working as an element in each cell, is it possible? In addition, I am not using storyboard.

```
import UIKit

class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Home"

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    collectionView?.register(WebCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 500)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
}

class WebCell: UICollectionViewCell {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

let StronaSzkolna: UIImageView = {
   let webview = UIImageView()
    webview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    webview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return webview
}()

func setupViews() {
    addSubview(StronaSzkolna)

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":StronaSzkolna]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-16-[v0]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":StronaSzkolna]))

    StronaSzkolna.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Have you tried replacing the `UIImageView` with a `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`?

Comment: Yes, it's working. But addnig code with URL and URLRequest and address is not working properly. You know how to do it?

Comment: Would you mind adding the code that performs the `URLRequest`?